# Hektic Oscillator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, elliptic-functions

It's fascinating that whereas the solution of the *quartic* oscillator (restoring force $\propto r^3$) problem can be expressed as the distance-from-origin of a point moving with unit speed along a lemniscate $r=\sqrt{\cos(2\theta)}$ (made a silly mistake there at first - fixed it now), the solution for an ordinary *quadratic* oscillator (restoring force $\propto r$) can likewise be expressed as the distance-from-origin of a point moving with unit speed along a *fattened* quasi-lemniscate $r=\cos\theta$ ... or two congruent circles just fitting within the unit circle.

Unlike as the case of the quartic oscillator, which can infact be elemenarily realised, a *prototype* realisation being transverse oscillations of a mass at the centre of a taught elastic string, I can't offhand think of how a *hektic* oscillator (restoring force $\propto r^5$) might simply be physically realised. Would that have its quasi-lemniscate?

I suppose it *must **exist*** ... it's the *solubility* of it, really, that raises the questions. I think the lobes would be rather *teardrop* -shaped ... on the grounds that as the exponent increases, the scenario becomes more like that of the particle simply *bouncing* off 'sheer walls' of force - so the lemniscate would tend more & more to be two increasingly  flattened 'blobs' each on the end of an  increasingly thin 'stalk' lying diametrically opposed to the other.

I think it might be one of those situations in which you have two figures, one for each of two scenarios one of which is one step further further along in a progression, that have a simple & beautiful relationship to each other; but in which when you try to extend it indefinitely it just starts getting kind of ... *ugly*. Quaternions - octonions, etc; exponentiation - tetration, etc ... it seems to happen with such *regularity*. And sometimes you just *so want* the progression to be extensible indefinitely!

**Update**

See answer.

Comment: I don't think 'Hektic' is the right word... maybe you mean 'quintic'?

Comment: Convention of denoting the kind of oscillator according to _the shape of the potential well_ rather than the shape of the restoring force _is_ actually one that is used ..

Comment: certainly "quartic oscillator" is used for an oscillator having a cubic _restoring force_. Physicists do seem to prefer to frame such things in terms of energy rather than force. It translates better into quantum mechanics, without a doubt ... which is of-a-piece with the way that in QM there no longer really is anymore a _thing_ with a trajectory. And preceding that, there were Lagrangian & Hamiltionian forms of mechanics. And in fluid mechanics you have velocity _potentials_, which end up-being what is solved-for. I think as a general rule physicists find the _integral_ form easier.

Comment: But now you mention it, it usually is Latin rather than Greek prefices that are used for things like that. Afterall it's "quartic" rather than "tetric" isn't it, & "quintic" rather that "pentic".

Comment: However, if it _were_ derived from Greek rather than Latin, it's not atall unlikely that it would be rendered "hektic" rather that "hextic", as in the old Greek from which these particles are taken there is a liberal use of _inflexion_ to 'relieve' difficult concatenation of consonants - and the substitution of 'κ' for 'ξ' in such a word would be a quite typical instance of such practice.

Comment: Yes, much better quintic.

Comment: Actually, I don't suppose it matters too much, as as the restoring force is always _odd_ & the potential always _even_, there is no hazard of misprision. But I very much doubt you'll persuade the physicists to change their habits!

Answer (score 1):

Now I think about it more carefully, I see that the lemniscate clearly *exists*: it can be *made* to exist by the expedient of setting (I'll just show case of an abstract dimensionless quasilemniscate)

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-r^{2n}}}=\sqrt{1+r^2\left(\frac{d\theta}{dr}\right)^2}$$

whence

$$\frac{d\theta}{dr}=\frac{r^{n-1}}{\sqrt{1-r^{2n}}}$$

whence (setting $u=r^n$)

$$n\theta=\operatorname{acos}u$$

whence $$r=(\cos(n\theta))^{1/n} .$$

So clearly there *is* always a solution-as-quasilemniscate for *any* positive integer value of $n$ - the problem of solving for it can be done very nicely 'short-circuiting' solving for the differential equation for $r$ in terms of time that results in evermore complex elliptic-type functions with increasing $n$. Relating length along the quasilemniscate to time is then just a matter of fetching in the characteristic length & time from the physical differential equation. And solving for $r$ in terms of *time* is then one with getting an explicit expression for $r$ in terms of arclength along the lemniscate, rather than in terms of $\theta$.

It's very pleasant to see that there *is* a beautifully simple answer to this question afterall! Wasn't expecting it. I feel *again* I ought to have seen it sooner!

It doesn't result in those *teardrop-shaped* lobes that I was expecting, though, does it: the lobes are just narrower & nearlier sharp-cornered. In fact, come to think of it, the idea of teardrop-shaped lobes is *extremely silly*, really, coz you'd need to have $\theta$ going *backwards* for part of its course!! In the limit of high $n$ they would tend to become just two line-segments, depicting the particle's behaviour tending towards bouncing backwards & forwards between elastic collisions. Which reminds me: I at first described the *elliptic function* solution of the cubic|quartic oscillator as being like a 'fattened' *sine* function: that's inaccurate, isn't it, as it's going to be somewhat morphing towards a *triangular sawtooth* waveform - the limit waveform, as just said.

I find it really quite astonishing, actually, just how strangely *fitting* the generalised lemniscate (or *quasi* -lemniscate, or *super* -lemniscate (by analogy with *superellipse*)) is for expressing - or *encapsulating* - the solution of the generalised (generalised in the sense of the restoring-force being proportional to *any **odd*** power of displacement) harmonic oscillator. And it's because the differential of arc length in polar co-ordinates, *and* the differential of time with respect to radius *in terms of* radius in the differential equation of the harmonic oscillator, *meld together* so conveniently to give an elementary integral in $r^n$ ... $n$ being by definition such that restoring force $\propto r^{2n-1}$ or shape of oscillator's *potential well* is of the form $r^{2n}$.

**UPDATE**

I've also just thought of how a hektic|pentic||sectic|quintic oscillator could be realised - and I don't know how it is I missed it: as in the quartic|cubic oscillator, affix the oscillating mass at the centre of a string ... but this time it doesn't need to be elastic, because instead of fixing the ends of the string to fixed points, each of them is *in turn* fixed to  the centre of a elastic string the ends of each of which are fixed to fixed points! Obviously this process can be continued *indefinitely ... **but***! ...  it would probably become so fragile you would need a *gravitiless environment* in which to set it up! But I've finally *clocked* how an oscillator of *any* degree could in principle be set-up!

Comment: I don't think there's much occasion or scope for the actual setting-up of such an oscillator - in fact designing it & optimising the positioning of the 2^(n-2)-1 strings would be an interesting mathematical question _in itself_ ... but I have heard advanced now & then the idea that if a machine or settup emonstrating some physical principle is at least _plausible_ then more likely than not there is some operation in nature _somewhere_ that is _isomorphic_ to the operation of _it_. I can't remember whether a name was cited in connection with any of these _mentionings_.

Comment: 2^(n-1) fixed fastening points & 2^(n-1)-1 strings, rather.

Comment: Actually, doing that _wouldn't_ yield an index of the restoring force of 2n-1, would it? It would rather be 2×3^(n-2)+1. Oh!! I _give up_!!

Comment: No ... 2^n-1. I'm _fairly_ sure about that now.

Comment: Interesting ! Do you have a reference for the case of a lemniscate you considered at first ?